# Configure routes angular for menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, routes, config

Confused with routes configuration in angular js. I want to learn how to configure this and don't import all the dependencies for each html file.

This is what I do not want to have foreach file:

```
  <script src="../../resources/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/toastr/toastr.min.css" />
<script src="../../resources/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../resources/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="../services/book.service.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/book.controller.js"></script>
```

1 - My appConfig.js with routes:

```
var app = angular.module("library.crud", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/book', {
              templateUrl: 'app/views/book.html',
              controller: 'bookController',
              controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/books', {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/books.html',
            controller: 'booksController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    })


    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}]);
```

How do I use the appConfig file ?

My index menu:

```
<html ng-app="library.crud">
  <script src="appConfig.js"> </script>

<body ng-app="library.crud">
  <a href="#/books">books</a>
  <a href="#/book">book</a>

  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My index file is not working and show the message: "injector moduler etc..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was supposed to be a comment, but I'd need 50 points of reputation.

You need to add the `angular-route.js` file to your page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Be careful with the AngularJS version you are using, the above is just an example.

Comment: Thank you!! now it is detecting the routes, but now it shows an error "403.14" "The web server is configured to not show a list of the contents of this directory."  when i click link to call route...  should I set up some security?

Comment: Absolutely! Probably `app/views` is configured to not be shown to external users. You should see the config of your Web server (Apache, IIS, Nginx, etc.).